# What does the unsubscribe button in Outlook (web) do?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

What does the "unsubscribe" button in Outlook (web) do?

I know most subscription emails allow you to unsubscribe by clicking a link in their emails (because of various laws in various jurisdictions that require this).

Does Outlook find and go through this type of link? Or do they just block emails from this address? What if the email address is used for both subscription emails and direct personal messages?

If the latter I guess it does not differentiate between these two types, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook Web (and some other mail clients) probably use the [RFC 2369 `List-Unsubscribe` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2369#section-3.2).

> The List-Unsubscribe field describes the command (preferably using mail) to directly unsubscribe the user (removing them from the list).

This header could contain a `mailto:` link or a standard web link. The result should be that the user is unsubscribed immediately, with no further questions.

So, no, the client will not block mails and it will also not comb the mail for the unsubscribe link.